# How to update/Insert at the same time using entity framework?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

How to update the existing Customer object, Insert new Computer object and Add new WorkOrder using entity framework ?

```
  Using trans As New System.Transactions.TransactionScope()
       Using dcLAIT As LAITEntities = New LAITEntities
                       -- Update Customer (Apply existing Customer)    
                    vWorkOrder.Customer = vCustomer
                       -- Insert Computer 
                    vWorkOrder.Computer = vComputer

                       -- Insert WorkOrder
                    dcLAIT.WorkOrder.AddObject(vWorkOrder)
                    dcLAIT.SaveChanges()
                    trans.Complete()
         End Using
   End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must attach the `Customer` separately and set its state before you connect it to added `WorkOrder`:

```
Using trans As New System.Transactions.TransactionScope()
   Using dcLAIT As LAITEntities = New LAITEntities
                   -- Insert Computer 
                vWorkOrder.Computer = vComputer

                   -- Insert WorkOrder
                dcLAIT.WorkOrder.AddObject(vWorkOrder)

                dcLAIT.Customer.Attach(vCustomer)
                   -- Update Customer (Apply existing Customer)    
                dcLAIT.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(vCustomer, EntityState.Modified)
                vWorkOrder.Customer = vCustomer
                dcLAIT.SaveChanges()
                trans.Complete()
     End Using
 End Using
```

Btw. `SaveChanges` uses transaction internally so unless you wanted to force Serialized isolation level or you are going to call multiple `SaveChanges` in that scope `TransactionScope` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

All pending changes on the Context should be executed when you call SaveChanges().  However, in cases where unique IDs are generated by the database, you may have to split inserts and updates into separate calls when inserting two new related entities.

Comment: Both Customer and Computer objects have identity generated by the database, In case of Insert the code works but not If I want to update one of the object.